# How to set a margin in a HTML element only when there are elements to the right

Tags: html, css

My question is: **How can I put a margin between the 2 elements, without misaligning them in smaller screens?**

I'm creating an HTML page with 2 elements disposed along a line, like this:

[image]

I made it responsive, so when I have a smaller screen, the elements are wrapped to another line:

[image]

Here's a fiddle to this: https://jsfiddle.net/5ye2sc4b/1/

**Html:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="line">
        <div class="element element1">Element 1</div>
        <div class="element element2">Element 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
     display:flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     margin-top: 10px;
 }

.header, .footer {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.line {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.element {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100px;
}
```

If I put a right margin in element 1, it will be displayed correctly in bigger screens:

```
element1 { margin-right: 20px; }
```

[image]

But it will be misaligned to the header on smaller screens:

[image]

On the fiddler above I put some buttons to change the global container size, to simulate the problem.

Comment: What is missing here is how you do and when happens the the wrapping breaking point.

Comment: First make sure your Fiddle is bugfree (1 div too many). And where are those buttons you mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

While i think your approach is not the best way to create a responsive layout you might want to simply remove the margin on smaller screens:

```
@media (max-width: 620px) {
margin-right: 0px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more suitable for CSS grid where you can use gaps:

```css
.container {
  /*display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; not really useful in this  case*/
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.header,
.footer {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.line {
  display: grid;
  /* adjust the 200px to control when elements will wrap */
  grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fit,minmax(200px,1fr));
  /* margin only between columns */
  grid-column-gap:16px;
}

.element {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="element element1">Element 1</div>
    <div class="element element2">Element 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using media queries:

Make sure your `.line` has `flex-flow: row nowrap;` the shorthand code for `flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;` initially.  The children should have a `flex-basis` of 50%

Then let the media query (`@media`) do the rest.

As soon as your screen goes below 900px, apply the CSS inside the media query like so:

```
@media(max-width: 900px){
.line{
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.element{
flex-basis: 100%;
}
.element1 {
margin-right: 0px;

}
```

this will remove the margin from your `element1` aswell as set the elements to 100% `flex basis`, aswell as the flex `wrap` on the `.line` for it to wrap.

```css
.container {
     display:flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     margin-top: 10px;
 }

.header, .footer {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.line {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.element {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100px;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.element1 { margin-right: 20px; }


@media(max-width: 900px){
.line{
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.element{
flex-basis: 100%;
}
.element1 {
margin-right: 0px;

}
```

```html
Html:

<div class="container">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="line">
        <div class="element element1">Element 1</div>
        <div class="element element2">Element 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```